# Fetter and Walecka's derivation of Goldstone's Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

I've been learning Green's Functions (Zero-Temprature) from Fetter and Walecka's *Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems*, and find it hard to understand the proof of Goldstone's Theorem, in page 111, the equation is:
$$[E-E_0]^{(n)}=⟨\Phi_0|\hat{H_1}\frac{1}{E_0-\hat{H_0}+i\epsilon n\hbar}\hat{H_1}\frac{1}{E_0-\hat{H_0}+i\epsilon (n-1)\hbar}...\hat{H_1}\frac{1}{E_0-\hat{H_0}+i\epsilon \hbar}\hat{H_1}|\Phi_0⟩_C$$
where C stands for connected. He noted that the limitation to connected diagrams ensures that $|\Phi_0⟩$ can not appear as an intermediate state and is nondegenerate. I'm confused with this statement.

Comment: Are you familiar with diagrammatic perturbation theory? You can prove the claim graphically to yourself if so. A disconnected diagram contributing to this correction would be the above expression with a $|\Phi_0><\Phi_0|$ inserted somewhere. This would be exactly a case where the state in question appears as an intermediate state.